# Remove line numbers at the start of each line

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I have numbers at the start of each line in my text file in the following format :

```
1: text written ....
2: text written ....
```

which continues upto 973 lines.
I want to delete any starting numbers with a space and a colon after it ...
How do I do it using regex in Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
^\d+\s:
```

If you can possibly have more than one space after it like this:

```
1   :
10  :
100 :
```

Use this pattern:

```
^\d+\s+:
```

Make sure you have *Wrap around* checked:
[image]

Comment: It throws error - can't find the text "^\d+\s:" . P.S. I have regular expressions ticked

Comment: @AdityaKumarPraharaj Try escaping the colon. Make it `^\d+\s\:`

Comment: @HamZa losing all indentation?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg make sure to update Notepad++ to version 6

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$
```