# Removing line numbers from textfile

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm currently trying to get rid of the line numbers from a file.

it has the following pattern:

```
LINENUMBER WHITESPACE REST
```

so I'm trying to replace anything before the first whitespace with a blank.

However, everytime I try that, it simply matches more than just anything before the whitespace.

`.+?(?=\ )` that's the regex I came up with.

What's wrong with that regex and why?

Comment: It is not anchored, use `^.+?(?= )` (almost equal to `^\S+`). Or since those a just numbers: `^\d+`

Comment: Also, see [Remove line numbers at the start of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395697/remove-line-numbers-at-the-start-of-each-line).